# Update query in java jdbc gives run time error

Tags: java, jdbc

This is a program for updating a table using [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) and it compiled successfully.

But at runtime gives error.

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class UpdateProfile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String fname = "ranjesh";
        String lname = "singh";
        String phone = "9870899645";
        String address = "ghz";
        String email = "sarwesh1206@gmail.com";

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE", "system", "oracle");

            //system is username and oracle is password
            //userinfo is name of table.

            String query = "UPDATE userinfo set fname = ? ,lname=?,mobile=?,address=? where email = ? ";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            pstmt.setString(1, fname); // set input parameter 1
            pstmt.setString(2, lname);
            pstmt.setString(3, phone);
            pstmt.setString(4, address);
            pstmt.setString(5, email);

            // set input parameter 2

            pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
            con.commit();
            con.close();
            System.out.print("success");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("error occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

Schema of table userinfo:

[image: schema of table userinfo]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Without that, I'm not sure we can help you.  Also, both your question and code are full of typos.  You might want to correct them.

Comment: Please mention the Error as part of question you were asked

Comment: Instead of printing "error occurred" in your catch-clause, use `ex.printStackTrace()` and add the full stack trace to your question.